# Android app sending a string to display on a webpage

Tags: php, android

I've been trying to create an Android app and webpage for months now, where the app sends a simple string to the website and the website displays that text. I've tried many tutorials, but they are all incomplete or old.

**SOLUTION**

As I am just a n00b as it comes to coding I wasn't able to tell whether the suggestions were the whole story or just a part of the story. It turned out that I only got a part of the story.

My objective was: to create an Android app and webpage, where the app sends a simple string to the website and the website displays that text *for everyone to see*. That last part I didn't mention in my question. So asking complete helps to get the right answer.

There were a couple of steps I had to take:

1. Register a domainname (that I did)
2. Contract a hosting service (that I did)
3. Upload a php-file with HasH's code (see below) to the file manager for your webpage in the topdirectory of that webpage, make sure that no content manager is running for that domain or subdomain (here I made a mistake: I had Parallels Presence Builder running on the target domain. Because it always uses a template I wasn't able to publish a 'clean' version of the php-file. That resulted in my webpage giving back junk information starting with `<!DOCTYPE` etc. I created a new subdomain without content management and uploaded a php-file with Hash's php-code. It worked perfectly)
4. Then I created the Android app using Hash's code (see below, don't forget the .jar-files AND don't forget to add the .jar-files as library!).
5. As my question was incomplete Hash's code doesn't deal with the part that the webpage has to display the text for everyone to see. As php is personal for every user I had to make an addition to the code.

See here:

```
<?php
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$myfile = fopen("yourfilename.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $msg . "\n");
fclose($myfile);    
}

$myfile = fopen("yourfilename.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("yourfilename.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: You have two connections. That is wrong. Stay with the first one.

Comment: stringToPost indeed does not contain a variable 'stringtopost'.

Comment: I changed it, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, let me give you a very simple way to connect your application with PHP Service page...
First you have to make sure you already has this libraries:
1- http-core-4.1.jar
2- httpclient-4.0.3.jar

Then create a new class name it "JSONParser" and paste this code:

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Well, now go to your main activity and do it as this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser(); 
 ProgressDialog pdialog;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

String msg = "Hello";

new connector().execute(msg); //This will create a new thread to connect with your service page.


}

//The AsyncClass connector..



 class connector extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pdialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pdialog.setMessage("Sending Hi...");
            pdialog.setCancelable(false);
            pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pdialog.show();
        }
        //ArrayList to carry your values
        List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                    data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg",params[0])); //here we sit the key "msg" to carry your value which you passed on thread execute.

  //Then create the JSONObject to make the rquest and pass the data(ArrayList).              
 JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest("Http://example.com/mypage.php","POST",data);

/*In case you want to receive a value from your page you should do something like this..
String getString = json.getString("key1");
Int getInt = json.getInt("key2");
key1,key2 are keys that you send from your page.
*/





            } catch (Exception e) {
               /* Any Exception here */
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
            pdialog.dismiss();
              // This After the thread did it's operate
/* For Example you Toast your key1,key2 values :D*/

            }
    }



}
```

In your PHP page you should do as the following..

```
<?php
//In case of receive..
$msg = $_POST['msg']; 
echo $msg;

//In case of send..
$values = array();
$values["key1"] = "Hello this is key1";
$values["key2"] = "Hello this is key2";
echo json_encode($values); //this will make a json encode which you can get it back in your application ;)

?>
```

Hope it helps :), and sorry for my bad English :v

Comment: Why are you introducing json? Nobody asked for it.

Comment: I just want to make full explanation :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I get this message in my browser: "Notice: Undefined index: msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\PostInput2.php on line 3
{"key1":"Hello this is key1","key2":"Hello this is key2"}"

Comment: Also in this line: "JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest("localhost/PostInput2.php","POST",data);", '"json" is greyed out: "Variable json is never used". Might there an issue?

Comment: This code will not going to work in your localhost, you have to host your web page online and then type your online host URL.. Try this free hosting [link](https://www.awardspace.com/).

Comment: OK, thanks, I've tried it with my live website, but now only getting: "{"key1":"Hello this is key1","key2":"Hello this is key2"}". So no "Hello".

Comment: Are you sure your Activity class passing a String parameter to the Async class? and make sure that you're using `$_POST['msg']` in your php page.

Comment: I'm not sure: in the `JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest("http://mywebsite.nl/homepage/targetpage/","POST",data);` `json` is still greyed out. `$_POST['msg']` is in the php-code. It's in a script and I'm using Parallels Presence Builder.

Comment: Is greyed doesn't mean that it's not working... I think you're missing something!

Comment: I'm using this code on my applications and it's working property.

Comment: I ran the app on a live device and a live website. Unfortunately still no change. Any ideas left?

Comment: Is it the full code, by the way, or do I need add anyhting else? I read a thread on serversockets as well.

Comment: Are you including the both libraries I've mentioned?

Comment: Yes I have. I've found this error: E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Which URL you're passing? Try to make sure it's valid!

Comment: And maybe a stupid question, but is the value `json` the incoming data from my website? I'm trying to send data from the android app to the webpage, not the other way around.

Comment: Listen bro,  I'm sure you're missing something.  About the URL you should pass the full path to your page like http:// mydomain.nl/mypage.php   after that echo the value..   Json is an object that should receive your json_encode function values,  also it send your values as a NaneValuePair array.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. I've found a .htaccess file in my websites' file manager saying: "Deny from all". Could that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: BTW,  if you're waiting your page to echo the msg it won't!!  You should save the variable in database when you send it via your application  and then call it back when your page is load.. htaccess I don't think it cause any problem!

Comment: OMG! I've been so stupid. Your code indeed works perfectly. I made two mistakes: my target website uses a template of parallel's presence builder which puts a lot "junk" in the JSONObject. With my filemanager I was able to make a "clean" page with only a string. Now it's clear to me that your works fine. My second stupid mistake is of course that a php session (or whatever you call it) is personal for each user. My objective was to be able to publish the string for everybody to see. Next step is your suggestion. To save the variable in a database call it on loading of the page. I'll get to you